# Saving the publish transaction package in Content manager and content Delivery

Tags: 2011, publishing, 2011-sp1, publishtransaction

I have one issue related to our Custom Anchor tags solution.

I want to analyze the Publish package both at content manager side and content delivery side.

Actually after the transaction is success, it is getting removed automatically.

Is there any way to store them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Content Delivery**

In your cd_deployer_conf.xml, modify the "Cleanup" attribute of the Queue Location element to be "false":

```
<Queue>
  <Location Path="c:\tridion\staging\incoming" WindowSize="20" Workers="10" Cleanup="false" Interval="2s"/>
</Queue>
```

Restart your deployer for these changes to take effect.

**Content Manager**

Modify your cd_transport_conf.xml, add a "Cleanup" attribute with the value of false to the Workfolder element:

```
<WorkFolder Location="./transactions" NotificationBatchSize="10" Cleanup="false"/>
```

The packages will appear in [TridionHome]\bin\transactions.

Restart the transport service for this change to take effect.

**DO NOT FORGET TO CHANGE THIS BACK AFTER YOUR INVESTIGATION** or face the wrath of some very annoyed users when your servers run out of disk space...